# Need to add Magins on Tags Module in sidebar on Blogger

Tags: html, widget, padding, blogger, margins

On the blog I'm working on - http://www.ourunitedvoice.org/- I have a "Tags" module in the left Sidebar and I can't add any padding/margins. I would like to have some space so that it doesn't flow into the elements.

Can someone help me determine what needs to changed in the HMTL? Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need changes in your CSS for this selector:

```
.sidebar #Label1 .widget-content {
   padding:5px;
}
```

If you can't acces your CSS file then you can make inline styles on your html:

```
<div class="widget-content cloud-label-widget-content" style="padding:10px">
```

Comment: Excellent! That really did the trick! Opened it up some of the sides. The bottom still merges into the "Archives" headers, but it's a great start! Thanks!

Comment: Then add also `margin-bottom:10px` don't forget check this as the answer if was helpfull